# How to add shading to object model in threeJS?

Tags: three.js

I have a custom-made object, an obelisk, next to a cube. The obelisk is made with `THREE.Geometry` (each vertex and face added manually), while the cube is made with `THREE.BoxGeometry`. They both use `THREE.MeshNormalMaterial`.

So why does the cube get colors that change with rotation, while the obelisk is just gray? I've managed to get other meshes to add color to the obelisk, but can't figure out how to get the sides to change colors during rotation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Washington Monument</title>
<style>
html, body {
  margin: 0; padding:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
canvas {
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="../../lib/three.min.js"></script>
<script>
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var fieldOfView = 45;
var aspect = window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight;
var nearClippingPlane = 0.01;
var farClippingPlane = 1000;
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fieldOfView, aspect, nearClippingPlane, farClippingPlane);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
var obeliskMaterial = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var obeliskGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
obeliskGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( 8.40, -80,     8.40));
obeliskGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( 8.40, -80,    -8.40));
obeliskGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-8.40, -80,    -8.40));
obeliskGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-8.40, -80,     8.40));
obeliskGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( 5.25,  72.36,  5.25));
obeliskGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( 5.25,  72.36, -5.25));
obeliskGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-5.25,  72.36, -5.25));
obeliskGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-5.25,  72.36,  5.25));
obeliskGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( 0,     89.29,  0));
obeliskGeometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 5), new THREE.Face3(0, 5, 4));
obeliskGeometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(1, 2, 6), new THREE.Face3(1, 6, 5));
obeliskGeometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(2, 3, 7), new THREE.Face3(2, 7, 6));
obeliskGeometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(3, 0, 4), new THREE.Face3(3, 4, 7));
obeliskGeometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(4, 5, 8));
obeliskGeometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(5, 6, 8));
obeliskGeometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(6, 7, 8));
obeliskGeometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(7, 4, 8));
var obeliskMesh = new THREE.Mesh(obeliskGeometry, obeliskMaterial);
scene.add(obeliskMesh);
var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(16, 16, 8);
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);
cube.position.x = 40;
scene.add(cube);
camera.position.z = 320;
var render = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  obeliskMesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
  cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  };
render();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `MeshNormalMaterial` in a custom geometry, you have to compute the normals of the geometry before creating the mesh:

```
obeliskGeometry.computeFaceNormals();
```

In your example:

```
[...]
obeliskGeometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(7, 4, 8));
obeliskGeometry.computeFaceNormals();
var obeliskMesh = new THREE.Mesh(obeliskGeometry, obeliskMaterial);
[...]
```